# PHP - IF doesn't check if the condition is true

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm creating a verb conjugator based on the endings of a verb that the user inputs.

For now it should work on verbs ending with "aic", "eic", "oic" (one array of endings) and "bic", "fic", "mic", "nic", "pic" and "wic" (another array of endings).

Unfortunately, it keeps assigning the first array to anything I put - even if it doesn't end with the specified endings.

This is the page: www.alweso.2ap.pl/koniugator/index.php

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$verb = $_POST["verb"];
$last2 = substr ($verb, -2);
$last3 = substr($verb, -3);
$last4 = substr($verb, -4);
$last5 = substr($verb, -5);
$last6 = substr($verb, -6);
$last7 = substr($verb, -7);
$last8 = substr($verb, -8);
$last9 = substr($verb, -9);

$root2 = str_replace($last2, "", $verb);
$root3 = str_replace($last3, "", $verb);
$root4 = str_replace($last4, "", $verb);
$root5 = str_replace($last5, "", $verb);
$root6 = str_replace($last6, "", $verb);
$root7 = str_replace($last7, "", $verb);
$root8 = str_replace($last8, "", $verb);
$root9 = str_replace($last9, "", $verb);


$aic_eic_oic = array("je", "isz", "i", "imy", "icie", "ja" );   
$bic_fic_mic_nic_pic_wic = array("ie", "isz", "i", "imy", "icie", "ia" );   
$cic_lic_sic_zic = array("e", "isz", "i", "imy", "icie", "a" ); 

?>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">

<?php

if ($last3 == ("aic" || "eic" || "oic")) {
        foreach ($aic_eic_oic as $one) {
        echo "<li>$root2$one</li>";
    }   
    }

elseif ($last3 == ("bic" || "fic" || "mic" || "nic" || "pic" || "wic")) {
        foreach ($bic_fic_mic_nic_pic_wic as $one) {
        echo "<li>$root2$one</li>";
        }
    }

    ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using the operators wrong – `$last3 == ("aic" || "eic" || "oic")` does _not_ do what you assume it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who told you that would work? Where did you read that? That isn't in any documentation; it doesn't work like that.

```
if( in_array($last3, array("aic","eic","oic")))

// ...

elseif( in_array($last3, array("bic","fic","mic","nic","pic","wic")))
```

Alternatively:

```
switch($last3) {
  case "aic":
  case "eic":
  case "oic":
    // do something
    break;
  case "bic":
  case "fic":
  case "mic":
  case "nic":
  case "pic":
  case "wic":
    // do something else
    break;
  default:
    // optional, do something to indicate error
}
```

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol - nobody told me it would work, I'm a newbie trying to cope with the whole pile of documentation and understand how to apply it. Learning means making mistakes. Anyway, your alternative answer works like a dream, so thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can't do `if($value = ($a || $b || $c))` do `if(in_array($value, array($a, $b, $c))`.
`if($value = ($a || $b || $c))` means : `$value == true`, because `'foo' || 'bar' || 'barfoo'` is evaluate as true (non-empty strings are alway true in php).

Answer (score 0):

your if statement syntax is incorrect, you cant do `if($last3 == (x || y || z))` because its illogical, this statement reads `if ($last3 == (x == true || y == true || z == true))

you must write it out fully:

`if ($last3 == x || $last3 == y || $last3 ==z)`

or use `in_array()`